# Detecting the rows of an array and finding common words of two arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, scanf

I have a filed called `a1.txt` which contains the words

`amazing
 malevolent
 permanent`

and another one called `a2.txt` with

`Amazing
Bridge
Malevolent`

Here is the code that I use to read the files into arrays, thanks to @M Oehm.

NOTE: `void b();` is the same as `void a()` but it reads `a2.txt` instead.

```
void a();
void b();
char (*a1)[50];
char (*a2)[50];
int n;    


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    a();
    printf("\n\n");
    b();
    int i=0, j=0;
    for (i; i < strlen(*a1); i++)
    {
        for (j; j <strlen(*a2); j++)
        {
            printf("\n%d", strcmp(a1[i], a2[j]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void a(){
FILE *f;          
int i;

f = fopen("a1.txt", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* first pass */
n = 0;
while (fscanf(f, "%*s") != EOF) n++;   /* star means: scan, but don't store */

a1 = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(*a1));
if (a1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* second pass */
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(f, "%49s", a1[i]);
}
*a1[n] = '\0';

/* process words */
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",a1[i]);
}}
```

As you can see the rows of the arrays are dynamic(I used three words as a test, however this should be done for an unknown amount of words hence the usage of `calloc`). Is it possible to detect the rows of each array and write the common words of each in a new file?
Finding the common words is a simple matter, I assume, of using `strstr`.

Comment: `a1[50] = calloc(1, lSize +1);` does not work. `a1` has only 50 elements.

Comment: You're right. I basically don't have a 2D array now and my allocation is useless. How can I fix that?

Comment: Are the source files in lexicographical sorted order? if so, you needn't full-buffer *either* input file, using instead to single line-buffer for each, and upon encountering a common word, dumping it to an output file. In other words, its a merge algorithm, but you ignore all non-identical rows and only output the ones you deem "matched". Also, is *case* sensitivity to be ignored? It actually makes the problem harder, not easier, if so.

Comment: By lexicographical you mean `A to Z` right? If so then yes they are sorted in that order. You suggest that I use `fgets`? Yes case sensitivity is ignored.

Comment: I **never** suggest `gets()`. that function is evil, immoral, and so vile it has been removed from the standard library. I suggest [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: If case sensitivity is ignored it gets a little harder, as you will need to decide whether `_stricmp()` (ISO and Windows) or `strcasecmp()` (POSIX), to do that bidding. Or write your own (which I don't advise).

Comment: Haha I mis-typed `fgets`. You can see I edited my comment. I don't understood anything from what you wrote. Let's assume that all the words are written in lowercase.

Comment: No worries, Hopefully the idea of just keeping one line per file active and how it can be used works with a pseudo-merge algorithm. Its utterly unrelated to the full-file-buffering you're attempting, which is why I mention it in a comment. Implemented properly, it makes full-file-buffering moot. I don't know if the purpose of your exercise it to actually *do* full-file-buffering. if so, then obviously your problem needs solving regardless If not, however, then your problem can be solved by simply not doing it in the first place =P

Comment: (Misclicked on chat). I'm just trying to practice C before my exam and I found a couple of exercises to do. It doesn't mention full-file-buffering. I only have to write the common words to another file.

Comment: [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/FXMwXw9J) was what I was referring to. I haven't tested it, but the idea should be self-explanatory. No allocations required. Sort of a backwards merge-function. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some misconceptions about memory allocation:

- `char *str[50]` creates an array of 50 (uninitialised) pointers of char. Perhaps you want `char (*str)[50]`, which is a pointer to an array of 50 chars, to which you can allocate memory.
- `lSize` is the length of the file, i.e. the number of chars. It looks a bit as if you wanted to count the number of words.

I'll present two strategies for reading words into a char array.

#### Read fixed-size words

This strategy uses a fixed word size of 50, as in your example. It opens the file and reads it in two passes. The first to determine the number of words, the next to read the actual words after allocating enough space.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char (*str)[50];    /* Pointer to words of max length 49 */
    int n;              /* number of words */
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: $fifo file_name.ip\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* first pass */
    n = 0;
    while (fscanf(f, "%*s") != EOF) n++;   /* star means: scan, but don't store */

    str = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(*str));
    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* second pass */
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(f, "%49s", str[i]);
    }
    *str[n] = '\0';

    /* process words */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%4d: '%s'\n", i, str[i]);
    }
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

This approach is reasonably simple, but it has two drawbacks: You will waste memory, because most words won't be 50 characters long. And you have to scan the file twice. Both drawbacks are not serious on modern computers.

#### Allocate as you go

You can also maintain the words as pointers to pointers to char, `char **str`. `str[i]` gives you a word, which is stored as pointer into existing memory of a null-terminated string. The function `strtok` gives you such strings.

This "existing memory"  is the contents of the file as char buffer. Rohan has shown you how to get ti: By getting the file length, allocating and reading.

This method takes only one pass, because it reallocates memory according to its needs. Start with space for, say, 64 words, read them, find out we need more, so reallocate to make 128 words fit, read words 64-127, and so on.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char *buf;          /* Buffer that hold the file's contets */
    size_t size;        /* Size of that buffer */
    char **str;         /* Array of pointers to words in that buffer */
    int n;              /* number of words */
    int nalloc;         /* For how many words space is allocated */
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: $fifo file_name.ip\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buf = malloc(size + 1);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read whoe file */
    fread(buf, 1, size, f);
    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(f);

    n = 0;
    nalloc = 0;
    str = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        if (n >= nalloc) {
            /* reallocate */
            nalloc = nalloc * 2;
            if (nalloc == 0) nalloc = 64;
            str = realloc(str, nalloc * sizeof(*str));
            if (str == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Reallocation failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        str[n] = strtok(n ? NULL : buf, " \t\n\r");
        if (str[n] == NULL) break;
        n++;
    }

    /* process words */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%4d: '%s'\n", i, str[i]);
    }
    free(buf);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

This approach is more efficient, but also more complicated. Note how many variables I need to keep track of everything: The llocated size, the actual size, the size of the text buffer. And I have to take care of two allocated arrays.

Given that you want to read *two*  files, it makes sense to pack these variables into a structure and read each file into such a structure.

#### Conclusion

These are only two of many ways to read words from a file. Both are not trivial and require that you understand how to manage memory.

I think one of the most basic things to learn is that a pointer may be used for many different things. It can just point to existing memory, whether that has been allocated or is an automatic array. But it can also be used as a handle to allocated memory; it will then behave like an array, excapt that you have to `free` the memory after use. You should not "move" such pointers, i.e. change the address they point to.

Both kinds of pointers look the same in your code, but you have to know which pointer acts as what.

Comment: I don't understand what `f = fopen(argv[1], "r");` does with `argv[1]`.

Comment: This example uses the first command line argument `argv[1]` as file name; in your example you can substitute is with `"a1.txt"` or with whichever filename you need.

Comment: Thanks it works. However, when I try to compare the two arrays using `strcmp()` it only returns `0` when I compare `a1[0] with a2[0]`. I will update my original post.

Comment: Hmmm. `strlen(*a1)` is the length of the first word in the word array `a1`. You want the length of the array, which you don't store. Yopu could return it from `a()` and `b()`. Also, if `a()` and `b()` only differ in which file they read, they should be made one function that operates on different data. No offence, but I have the impression that you need to get a better grasp on basic data management and functions before you can tackle this.

Comment: Yeah I'm still learning. As I said in a comment above I'm practicing and trying to understand C still. Is it that bad to have two different functions?

Comment: It's unusual to have two nearly identical functions; they would usually be "refactored" into one. It's a habit you'll develop with time. Your problam at the moment is that strings in C are arrays of char, and hence your words array is really an array of arrays. Perhaps you should play a bit with one-dimensional arrays - automatic and allocated - to get a better "feeling" for them?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
char *a1[50];
char *a2[50]; //not used so can remove
```

You are creating array of char pointers, not array of characters. You may want to just use char pointers as

```
char *a1;
char *a2;
```

Then instead of

```
a1[50] = calloc(1, lSize +1);
```

do

```
a1 = calloc(1, lSize +1);
```

Using `a1[50]` as in your code is incorrect and will cause undefined behavior (including segmentation fault). The array elements are from 0 to 49, so last element is `a1[49]`.

Also, you can use `lSize` to read those many characters as below

```
for (i=0; i <lSize; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(file, "%c", &a1[i]) == 1){
        printf("%c", a1[i]);
    }
}
```

But may be you can skip the for loop limit and read from file until there is no error.

Comment: That's what I did at the start but for some reason I thought it was wrong. However, this still gives me a 1D array, does it not? How can I count the amount of words in it?

Comment: @user3601507, The answer fixes your basic program to read a file into an array. You need to think more about how you want to break the files into multiple lines/words and read into 2D array.